# CMake library dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake

This may be a tad hard to explain in full. I have setup a directory structure for a series of C++ libraries I am writing. I intend to use CMake to handle building these libraries. For the most part these libraries are completely separate "subsystems" but in the odd places one library needs access to the header file contained within another. Here is my directory structure.

```
base
 ├─ cmake
 ├─ docs
 ├─ examples
 └─ sources
    ├─ libA
    │   ├─ include
    │   │   └─ libA
    │   │       ├─ core.h
    │   │       └─ *.h
    │   ├─ source
    │   │   └─*.cpp
    └─ libB
        ├─ include
        │   └─ libB
        │       ├─ message.h
        │       └─ *.h
        └─ source
            └─ *.cpp
```

There are `CMakeLists.txt` files in a few places. The main one is within the root directory `base` which sets up a bunch of variables and options and lastly calls `add_subdirectory(sources)`. Within `sources` the `CMakeLists.txt` file simply calls:

```
add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
```

Lastly there are `CMakeLists.txt` files in both the `libA` and `libB` directories. These are both largely the same except for the target name. An example of one of these files is:

```
set(target libA)

# Sources
set(include_path "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${target}")
set(source_path  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source")

# Add include directories
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

# Set the source files to compile
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources ${source_path}/**/*.cpp)

# Build library
add_library(${target} ${sources})
```

Now separately both of these libraries can be built without issue but I need to be able to include a header from `libA` in a source file within `libB`

```
// base/sources/libB/source/message.cpp

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#include <libA/core.h>
#include <libB/message.h>
```

However when I build this I get the following error:

```
fatal error: 'libA/core.h' file not found
```

I have tried using `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories` without any luck. Clearly I am using these wrong or simply don't understand what each of these do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to your `CMakeLists.txt` for `libB`, another include directory:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libA/include")
```

Comment: Maybe `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.."` because `<libA/core.h>` is used.

Comment: @RedUser, No, actually the complete path is `../libA/include/libA/core.h`

Answer (score 14):

Since your library `libB` needs a header from `libA` to compile, let's say `libA` is a dependency of `libB`. Fortunately, CMake is very clever at handling dependencies, so your job is pretty easy:

## libA

Instead of

```
# Add include directories
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

add to the end

```
target_include_directories(${target} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

This will tell CMake that it must also include the headers for `libA` to the other projects that need it.

## libB

Just tell CMake that libB needs libA:

```
target_link_libraries(${target} libA)
```

Note that this doesn't relate directly to the linking step when you compile. For libraries it mainly tells that there is this dependency, and in this case it will automatically add the paths for the headers automatically.

Comment: This is the modern way! For the sake of consistency, you should user PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE for the target_link_libraries call too!